# Multiple transformations of a string with backslashes

Tags: string, python-3.x, escaping, backslash

I'm getting completely confused with string encodings in Python. I read a number of other answers, but none show, what is really going on in the last three lines of the code below:

```
filename = "/path/to/file.txt" #textfile contains only the string "\bigcommand"

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    file = list(f)

val = file[0]                         #val = '\\bigcommand\n'
valnew = val.encode('unicode-escape') #valnew = b'\\\\bigcommand\\n'
valnewnew = str(valnew,'utf-8')       #valnewnew = '\\\\bigcommand\\n'
```

Why is the `valnew` variable suddenly a bytestring? I thought it would be the same as before - but just with the escape characters doubled?

Is there a shorter way to do this, than the convoluted last three lines, in order to get the output of `valnewnew`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the output of valnewnew:

```
val = file[0].encode('unicode-escape').decode()
with open('t', 'r') as f:
    file = list(f)

    val = file[0].encode('unicode-escape').decode() # value: '\\\\bigcommand\\n'
```

When you encode a string in python3.x, you're encoding the string into bytes which then needed to be subsequently decoded to get a string back as a result.

If you give some insight into what you're trying to do, I can try expand.